# Motherboard HDMI Version

Tags: hdmi, specifications

My motherboard is the [msi z68a-gd65 g3](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/Z68AGD65_G3.html). It has an HDMI port. I have carefully read the user manual, but I cannot find which [HDMI version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions) is supported. Is there another way to find out ?

The motherboard was released in may 2011, HDMI 1.4a was released in march 2010 and 1.4b in october 2011. So it may support 1.4a at best.

If this information cannot be found, am I safe using a 2.0b cable ? I've read HDMI is backward compatible with previous versions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: HDMI cables are compatible between the different HDMI port versions, with the only things that differ are the bit depth and resolution/framerate they support (the exception to this are 4K certified cables).  If needing new HDMI cables, I always recommend [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com), as they lifetime warranty all their cables, all of which are high quality, yet inexpensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I cannot find which HDMI version is supported

From the [link you quoted in the question](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/Z68AGD65_G3.html):

> **HDMI v1.4**
>
> HDMI (High-Definition Multimedia Interface) is new generation fully
>   digital video/audio interface which can transfer 1080p High-Definition
>   video and Audio output in single compact connector. Supporting HDCP
>   copy protection such as Blu-ray Discs, HDMI provides you with the
>   highest-quality home theater experience.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Next-Gen Multimedia Interface
> - Deliver Full HD Video & Audio output In Only One Cable (**HDMI 1.4 is only supported with 2nd Intel®Generation CoreTM Processors. Pentium
>     and Celeron Processors support HDMI 1.3**)